# Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to int

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-8, import-from-excel

I want to Import data excel to my database, with rules if 'stok'[row 5] > 2 columns of 'keterangan' will be filled 'Tersedia', else if 'stok'[row 5] !=0 2 columns of 'keterangan' will be filled 'Hampir Habis', else columns of 'keterangan' will be filled 'Habis'. what code should I write to the controller of import data? I'm using laravel version 8

This is the code of import

```
<?php

public function model(array $row)
    {
        $product_status = Produk::where('stok', $row[5]);
        if ($product_status > 2) {
            $ket= new Produk([
                'keterangan'     => "Tersedia",]);
            $ket->save();
        } elseif ($product_status != 0) {
            $ket= new Produk([
                'keterangan'     => "Hampir Habis",]);
            $ket->save();
        } else {
            $ket= new Produk([
                'keterangan'     => "Habis",]);
            $ket->save();
        }
        return new Produk([
            'kode_barang'     => $row[0],
            'jenis_barang'    => $row[1],
            'nama_barang'    => $row[2],
            'tipe'    => $row[3],
            'kategori_id'    => $row[4],
            'stok'    => $row[5],
            'harga'    => $row[6],
            'harga_beli'    => $row[7],
            
        ]);
    }

public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
        '0' => function ($attribute, $value, $onFailure) {
            if (Produk::where('kode_barang', '=', $value)->count() > 0) {
                $onFailure('tersedia');
            } elseif ($value == null || $value == '') {
                $onFailure('kosong');
            } elseif ($value == 0) {
                $onFailure('nol');
            }
        },
        '1' => 'required|string',
        '2' => 'required|string',
        '5' => 'required|numeric',
        '6' => 'required|numeric',
        '7' => 'required|numeric',
    ];
    }
}
```

this is the controller

```
public function imporproduk(Request $request){
       // validasi
        $this->validate($request, [
            'file' => 'required|mimes:csv,xls,xlsx'
        ]);
        // menangkap file excel
        $file = $request->file('file');
        // membuat nama file unik
        $nama_file = rand().$file->getClientOriginalName();
        // upload ke folder file_produk di dalam folder public
        $file->move('file_produk/',$nama_file);
        // import data
        Excel::import(new ProdukImport, 'file_produk/'.$nama_file);
        // notifikasi dengan session
        Alert::success('sukses','Data produk Berhasil Diimport!');

        // alihkan halaman kembali
        return redirect()->back();

    }
```

The error said **Property [stok] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.**

Sorry I'm a newbie using laravel 8

Comment: Which line is related with the error?

Comment: I think this one:  $product_status = Produk::where('stok', $row[5]);, it should end with get() or count()

Comment: but now the error said SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'kode_barang' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `produks` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2021-01-10 04:04:00, 2021-01-10 04:04:00))
if i change position return new product to the top of the Product::where, the query is working but column of keterangan still fill with default value "Tersedia"

Comment: @sta the line of $product_status = Produk::where('stok', $row[5]);
        if ($product_status > 2) {

Comment: If its a single product, then change it to `$product_status = Produk::where('stok', $row[5])->first();`